# Integration of $e^{it}$

Tags: real-analysis, integration

I am pretty sure that
$$\bigg|\int_{A}e^{it}\,dt\bigg|\leq2$$
for every measurable set $A\subseteq[-\pi,\pi]$,
but I cannot prove this...

Comment: If you could prove $|\int_{A}\cos(t)\mathrm{d}t|+|\int_{A}\sin(t)\mathrm{d}t|\leq 2,$ this would be enough, and it would also imply that the maximum is achieved only for $A=[-\pi/2,\pi/2],\,[0,\pi],\,[-\pi,0]$, or $[-\pi,-\pi/2]\cup[\pi/2,\pi],$ by inspecting the equality condition.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We avoid arguments that use the modulus (i.e. triangle inequality) since for some measurable sets, for instance $A = [-\pi, \pi]$, we have an overestimate $$\Big|\int_A e^{it}dt\Big| \leq 2 < \int_A|e^{it}|dt = 2\pi$$

Simply by rotating the value of the integral (which is a complex number) back to the real numbers.

Let $f(t) = e^{it}$. Since $\int_A f dt$ is a complex number, it has magnitude and phase $$\int_A f dt = \Big|\int_A f dt\Big| e^{i\theta}$$ for some $\theta \in [-\pi, \pi]$. Note that $\theta$ is independent of time, hence
$$\Big|\int_A f dt\Big| = \int_A f e^{-i\theta} dt$$ 
The integrals are real valued, hence we consider the real component only $$\int_A f e^{-i\theta} dt = \int_A \mathfrak{Re}(f e^{-i\theta}) dt = \int_A \cos(t - \theta) dt$$

It remains to prove that the real integral $ \int_A \cos(t - \theta) dt \leq 2$.

*Hint.* $\cos(t-\theta)$ is non-negative for $t-\theta \in [-\pi/2, \pi/2]$, so we are interested in such elements of $A$, denote them by $A^+$, so that $$\int_A  \cos(t-\theta) dt \leq \int_{A^+} \cos(t-\theta) dt \leq \int_{[-\pi/2, \pi/2]} \cos(t)dt = 2$$

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

We have
$$ I=\int_a^be^{it}dt=\frac{1}{i}(e^{ib}-e^{ia}) $$
Then
$$ |I|=|-i||e^{ib}-e^{ia}|=|e^{ib}||1-e^{i(b-a)}|\le |1|+|e^{i(b-a)}|\le 1+1=2$$

Comment: This proves the result for the case that $A$ is an interval, but I don't see that it covers all measurable $A$ immediately.

Comment: Oh I see. My bad! Thanks for your advice!

Comment: $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}e^{it}=0$, but if $A=[-\pi/2,\pi/2],$ then $\left|\int_{A}e^{it}\right|=2.$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $e^{it}=\cos t + i \sin t$ and split $[-\pi,\pi]$ into the regions $[-\pi,-\pi/2],[-\pi/2,0],[0,\pi/2],[\pi/2,\pi]$. How do $\cos$ and $\sin$ behave on these regions?